# Replace regex until no match found

Tags: regex, vbscript

How to execute regex replace until all are replaced?

For example after 4 time replacement with `"(\w{3} \d{1,9})\r?\n\w{2} (\d)"` by `"$1$2"` gives the result.

**Text:**

```
foo 1
ba 1
ba 2
ba 3
ba 4
foo 2
ba 1
ba 2
foo 3
ba 1
ba 2
ba 3
```

**Result:**

```
foo 11234
foo 212
foo 3123
```

Example code:

```
Dim regEx_, stxt
stxt = "foo 1" & VBcr & "ba 1" & VBcr & "ba 2" & VBcr & "ba 3" & VBcr _
  & "ba 4" & VBcr & "foo 2" & VBcr & "ba 1" & VBcr & "ba 2" & VBcr _
  & "foo 3" & VBcr & "ba 1" & VBcr & "ba 2" & VBcr & "ba 3"

Set regEx_ = New RegExp
With regEx_
  .Global = True
  .MultiLine = True
  .IgnoreCase = True
  .Pattern = "(\w{3} \d{1,9})[\r?\n]\w{2} (\d)"
  stxt = regEx_.Replace(stxt, "$1$2")
  stxt = regEx_.Replace(stxt, "$1$2")
  stxt = regEx_.Replace(stxt, "$1$2")
  stxt = regEx_.Replace(stxt, "$1$2")
  stxt = regEx_.Replace(stxt, "$1$2") 'to make sure (real example some time contains up to 30 replacements)
End With
MsgBox stxt
```

Is there any way I can replace until no match found? Like this:

```
Do Until regEx_.Test(stxt)
  stxt = regEx_.Replace(stxt, "$1$2")
Loop
```

Comment: What is the question and what is the expected output?

Comment: Try `[\r\n]+\w{2}\s+` regex to replace with an empty string.

Comment: This is close. but not every ba are needs to be replaced. Only ba that are preceded by foo. But thanks. I didn't thought but didn't expected the result.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't need a loop if you modify your expression a little and use a [replacement function](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms974619.aspx#scripting12_topic4) with a second regular expression to remove all non-digits from the two-letter lines:

```
Function Merge(m, sm1, sm2, pos, src)
  Set re = New RegExp
  re.Global  = True
  re.Pattern = "\D"

  Merge = sm1 & re.Replace(sm2, "")
End Function

Set regEx_ = New RegExp
regEx_.Global  = True
regEx_.Pattern = "(\w{3} \d{1,9})((?:[\r?\n]\w{2} \d)+)"

stxt = regEx_.Replace(stxt, GetRef("Merge"))
```

`((?:[\r?\n]\w{2} \d)+)`: The modification I made to your regular expression uses a non-capturing group (`(?:...)`) to match one or more (`+`) subsequent two-letter lines. The outer set of parentheses then captures the subsequent two-letter lines in a single group that's passed as the second submatch (`sm2`) to the replacement function.

The replacement function uses a second regular expression to remove all non-digit characters (`\D`) from the two-letter lines, leaving just the digits, which are then concatenated to the first submatch (`sm1`, `(\w{3} \d{1,9})`).

Basically, a string like this:

```
foo 1
ba 1
ba 2
ba 3
ba 4
```

gives two submatches `sm1`:

```
foo 1
```

and `sm2` (with a leading linebreak):

```
ba 1
ba 2
ba 3
ba 4
```

The replacement function then removes everything except numbers from `sm2`:

```
1234
```

and appends that to `sm1`:

```
Merge = "foo 1" & "1234"
```

Comment: Very much complex. Let me understand.

Answer (score 2):

You were close. Try this one.

```
Do While regEx_.Test(stxt)
    stxt = regEx_.replace(stxt, "$1$2")
Loop
```